# How to control the order of facet gird rows and/or columns in xarray?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, python-xarray

I am trying to change the order of variables I use to make a facet grid in xarray. For example, I have **[a,b,c,d**] as column names. I want to reorder it to **[c,d,a,b]**. Unfortunately, unlike [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html), I could not find parameters such as col_order or row_order in xarray plot function (

> https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.plot.FacetGrid.html

**Update:**
To help myself better explain what I need, I took the example below from the user guide of xarray:
In the following example, I need to change the place of months. I mean, for example, I want to put the month 7 as the first column and 2nd month as the 5th and so on and so forth. [image]

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature.nc").rename({"air": "Tair"})

# we will add a gradient field with appropriate attributes
ds["dTdx"] = ds.Tair.differentiate("lon") / 110e3 / np.cos(ds.lat * np.pi / 180)
ds["dTdy"] = ds.Tair.differentiate("lat") / 105e3
ds.dTdx.attrs = {"long_name": "$∂T/∂x$", "units": "°C/m"}
ds.dTdy.attrs = {"long_name": "$∂T/∂y$", "units": "°C/m"}
monthly_means = ds.groupby("time.month").mean()
# xarray's groupby reductions drop attributes. Let's assign them back so we get nice labels.
monthly_means.Tair.attrs = ds.Tair.attrs
fg = monthly_means.Tair.plot(
    col="month",
    col_wrap=4,  # each row has a maximum of 4 columns
)
plt.show()
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Because it is a project dataset, I could not share the original one with you. Hence, I have borrowed a sample script from the xarray guide page. It is now added to my question.

Comment: If I understand the answer correctly, in your example code you could try `monthly_means.Tair.sel(month=np.append(np.arange(0, 31, 3) % 11 + 1, 12)).plot(col="month", col_wrap=4)` to plot the months column wise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xarray will respect the shape of your data, so you can rearrange the data prior to plotting:

```py
In [2]: ds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature.nc")

In [3]: ds_mon = ds.groupby("time.month").mean()

In [4]: # order the data by month, descending
   ...: ds_mon.air.sel(month=list(range(12, 0, -1))).plot(
   ...:     col="month", col_wrap=4,
   ...: )

Out[4]: <xarray.plot.facetgrid.FacetGrid at 0x16b9a7700>
```

[image: plot with monthly average air temperatures arranged in descending order]

Comment: Thanks alot. If I got it right, sell (isel) changes the initial levels of elements, which is based on alphabetical or numerical order. Anyhow, the key point was using sel/isel. But, to make it fit my case, I created a month list like [7,2,5,...]. Anyhow, your suggestion worked for me.

Comment: yep, I used a range for convenience but the positional or label-based indices can be any ordering you want. they don't even have to be unique, so if you really wanted to plot `ds.sel(month=[2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2])` you could do that!